# Type mismatch when changing Theme from options menu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, android-preferences, android-optionsmenu

I'm trying to change the app theme during runtime from an options menu item click but it's not working and my app keeps crashing. What's the correct way to reslove this error? Android Studio doesn't provide any suggestions whatsoever, let alone helpful ones.

> java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val prefTheme = "preference_DarkTheme"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        useDarkTheme = shouldUseDarkTheme()
        setTheme(
            if (useDarkTheme) R.style.DarkTheme
            else R.style.LightTheme
        )

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        if (useDarkTheme != shouldUseDarkTheme()) recreate()
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_changeTheme -> {
                switchTheme()
                restartActivity()

                Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                true
            }
            else -> { super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) }
        }
    }

    private fun getSavedTheme(): Int {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .getInt(prefTheme, R.style.LightTheme)
    }

    private fun switchTheme() {
        val newTheme: Int =
            if (getSavedTheme() == R.style.LightTheme) R.style.DarkTheme else R.style.LightTheme
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .edit()
            .putInt(prefTheme, newTheme)
            .apply()
    }

    private fun restartActivity() {
        startActivity(
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        )
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        finish()
    }

    private fun shouldUseDarkTheme(): Boolean =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(
            "preference_DarkTheme",
            false
        )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting value of prefTheme as Int in setNewTheme() and get it as Boolean in shouldUseDarkTheme() For Solution of your problem is store one int for style and one another boolean for check to apply dark theme or not.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val prefTheme = "preference_DarkTheme"
private val applydarktheme = "applydarktheme"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    useDarkTheme = shouldUseDarkTheme()
    setTheme(
        if (useDarkTheme) R.style.DarkTheme
        else R.style.LightTheme
    )

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    if (useDarkTheme != shouldUseDarkTheme()) recreate()
}


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return true
}


override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_changeTheme -> {
            switchTheme()
            restartActivity()

            Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            true
        }
        else -> { super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) }
    }
}

private fun getSavedTheme(): Int {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        .getInt(prefTheme, R.style.LightTheme)
}

private fun switchTheme() {
    val newTheme: Int =
        if (getSavedTheme() == R.style.LightTheme){ R.style.DarkTheme} else{ R.style.LightTheme}

    if (newTheme== R.style.DarkTheme){
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean(applydarktheme, true)
            .apply()
    }else{
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean(applydarktheme, false)
            .apply()
    }


    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        .edit()
        .putInt(prefTheme, newTheme)
        .apply()
}

private fun restartActivity() {
    startActivity(
        Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    )
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    finish()
}

private fun shouldUseDarkTheme(): Boolean =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(
        applydarktheme,
        false
    )
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code that *writes* a boolean to SharedPreferences, but you do have code that *reads* a boolean:

> ```
> private fun shouldUseDarkTheme(): Boolean =
>     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(
>         "preference_DarkTheme",
>         false
>     )
> ```

That makes me assume that, at some point in the past, you had code that wrote a boolean value using that key.

Now you have code that reads an `Int` value, but it uses the same key as the previous boolean code:

> ```
> private val prefTheme = "preference_DarkTheme"
>
> private fun getSavedTheme(): Int {
>     return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
>         .getInt(prefTheme, R.style.LightTheme)
> }
> ```

You'll have to go through your app and make sure that anything that reads/writes a boolean and anything that reads/writes an int use different keys.

Comment: I think I used `private val prefTheme = "pref"` when I shouldn't have. Is there a way to use an option menu item click event to check the current theme, then switch to a different theme (if need be) and restart the Activity with a fade transition? i.e. `startActivity(
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        )
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);` in realtime? Reading the `preference_DarkTheme` preference is fine as I know it would change the whole app's preference.